# QGIS Atlas -- Scale bar changes for different maps

Tags: qgis, atlas, scale-bar

I'm able to generate maps using the Atlas tool.

I set the "Fixed scale" for the map and the scale bar as "Fixed width". But the scale bar length still changes for each map even map scale stays the same.

This is the setting of scale bar

[image: This is the settings of scale bar]

This is the first map's scale bar:

[image: 1st map scale bar]

And then, if I move to another map, it will be this

[image]

If you look closely at the image, the length of the scale bar slightly changes.

How can I fix this issue?

Is this the correct setting?

[image]

Comment: Please post an image of how you fixed the map scale and the scale bar to see what is going wrong.

Comment: @ahmadhanb, updated.

Comment: Check if the answer solved your problem.

Comment: @ahmadhanb, hey. I tried to edit, but not very sure I pasted the value to the right place. I already set up the other steps. Thanks!! The Data defined Override is not available for me to edit.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the scale from the `Map item → Main Properties → Scale`. Here are the steps to do that:

1. Write a proper scale value based on the extent of the largest feature. Then, copy the scale value and paste it into the `Data Defined Override`. It turned yellow color, as you can see in the image below.
2. Activate `Controlled by Atlas`
3. Select `Fixed Scale`

[image]

The scale bar will not change (expand or shrink) after that. Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering!!